# udev rules not working for ThinkPad X200 dock

Tags: linux, archlinux, udev

Learning this as I go, so excuse me if I'm totally missing the point.

I'm running Arch on a ThinkPad X200 and I want to get the dock to work so that I can sit at my desk charging and displaying to an external monitor. I have been working on this issue for nearly a week trying many different things and different approaches, udev being the one I think will work best.

Here is the udev output for when it's docked:

```
UDEV  [7979.317053] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/027
DEVNUM=027
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_5
ID_MODEL=1005
ID_MODEL_ENC=1005
ID_MODEL_ID=1005
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:5
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_5
ID_REVISION=0001
ID_SERIAL=17ef_1005
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090001:090002:
ID_VENDOR=17ef
ID_VENDOR_ENC=17ef
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Lenovo
ID_VENDOR_ID=17ef
MAJOR=189
MINOR=26
PRODUCT=17ef/1005/1
SEQNUM=2995
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:seat:
TYPE=9/0/2
USEC_INITIALIZED=7975952454
```

Here is the udev output for when it's undocked:

```
UDEV  [7996.175393] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/027
DEVNUM=027
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=26
PRODUCT=17ef/1005/1
SEQNUM=3003
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=9/0/2
USEC_INITIALIZED=7996171763
```

Here is the udev rule I created:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{PRODUCT}=="17ef/1005/1",  RUN+="/usr/local/bin/docked.sh"
```

This is the `/usr/local/bin/docked.sh` script I made using dockd to handle monitor output:

```
#!/bin/bash

dockd --set docked
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, and I appologize if I left anything out that is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or should be asked on the Archlinux (Arch-General) mailing list `arch-general@archlinux.org` or the [Archlinux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, but there are some slight tweaks here.

First up:  Most of those values you are seeing aren't `ATTR`, they're `ENV`.  On top of that `ENV` values don't happen early so make sure they happen later.

In other words, this should look like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="ADD", ENV{PRODUCT}=="17ef/1005/1",  RUN+="/usr/local/bin/docked.sh"
```

You'll notice a second change.  The capitalization of the action `ADD`.

Alas, udev is case sensitive.

Digging in further though...

`ATTR` values (alas) aren't directly referencing udev values.  Instead they're referencing *`sysfs`* values.  Let's break it down:

Given the device `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5`

And the udev rule:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{PRODUCT}=="17ef/1005/1",  RUN+="/usr/local/bin/docked.sh"`

You'll be hunting through the path `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-5` (literally that path on the filesystem) at from there it's going to look in a file called `PRODUCT`.  Chances are, that file doesn't exist (or if it does the content isn't `17ef/1005/1`).  Given a similar Thinkpad dock this is what I have:

When running `udevadm monitor -p -s usb`, I get this (abbreviated) in my output:

```
UDEV  [199584.676830] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/104
DEVNUM=104
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
ID_MODEL=Lenovo_ThinkPad_Dock
ID_MODEL_ENC=Lenovo\x20ThinkPad\x20Dock\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=1012
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
ID_REVISION=5040
ID_SERIAL=LENOVO_Lenovo_ThinkPad_Dock
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:090000:
ID_VENDOR=LENOVO
ID_VENDOR_ENC=LENOVO\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Lenovo
ID_VENDOR_ID=17ef
MAJOR=189
MINOR=103
PRODUCT=17ef/1012/5040
SEQNUM=6492
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:seat:
TYPE=9/0/1
USEC_INITIALIZED=199583756948
```

On the other hand when I run `udevadm info -a -p` with the *sysfs* device path I get more useful info:

```
$ udevadm info -a -p  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4':
    KERNEL=="1-4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="5040"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTR{busnum}=="1"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{devnum}=="104"
    ATTR{devpath}=="4"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="1012"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="LENOVO                 "
    ATTR{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTR{product}=="Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   "
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTR{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTR{speed}=="480"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="31"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0413"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.13.16-100.fc25.x86_64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="12"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="2287"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x9d2f"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="123"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x21"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2233"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

When I dig into my sysfs directory for that device I see the following:

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root     0 Jan 18 13:27 1-4:1.0
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root     0 Jan 18 13:27 1-4.4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 authorized
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 avoid_reset_quirk
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 bcdDevice
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 bConfigurationValue
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 bDeviceClass
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bDeviceProtocol
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bDeviceSubClass
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bmAttributes
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bMaxPacketSize0
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bMaxPower
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bNumConfigurations
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 bNumInterfaces
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 busnum
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 configuration
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 65553 Jan 18 13:27 descriptors
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 dev
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 devnum
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 devpath
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     0 Jan 18 13:27 driver -> ../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     0 Jan 18 13:55 ep_00
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 idProduct
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 idVendor
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 ltm_capable
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 manufacturer
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 maxchild
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     0 Jan 18 13:49 port -> ../1-0:1.0/usb1-port4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Jan 18 13:27 power
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 product
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 quirks
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 removable
--w-------. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 remove
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 speed
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     0 Jan 18 13:27 subsystem -> ../../../../../bus/usb
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:27 uevent
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 urbnum
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  4096 Jan 18 13:49 version
```

The key part is correlating the `udevadm info` (rather than `udevadm monitor`) data to the location in `/sysfs`.  You'll notice that in my `info` output I've got:

```
ATTR{bcdDevice}=="5040"
...
ATTR{idProduct}=="1012"
ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef"
```

And, low and behold:

```
$ cd /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
$ cat bcdDevice 
5040
$ cat idProduct 
1012
$ cat idVendor
17ef
```

Hopefully this gives you enough to get you over the finish line!